# table not extracted and not saved in csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the table but my code seems like not working as it returns the value none
i wanted to extract it with xpath but i couldnt try xpath as i have no knowledge and i am little bit familiar with beautifulsoup. how can i extract this table and save in csv?
the website i am using is :https://training.gov.au/Organisation/Details/31102

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://training.gov.au/Organisation/Details/31102'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('tabel', id = 'ScopeQualification')

print(table)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to format your code as code blocks, using back ticks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to extract the values of that table the best way is pandas
here's a cheat sheet for it so you can get exactly what you want
https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf